# How can I point the react api service point to hit my domain rather than localhost:8000

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config, vultr

I have deployed my react app in `Vultr` server and installed `nginx` in server and configured the  below settings by running below command.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name somedomain-test.com www.somedomain-test.com;
    root /var/www/somedomain-test.com/build;
    index index.html;
}
```

I did ran `npm run build` and copied the build folder into the following destination folder `/var/www/automateandmore.com/build`

Then ran below commands:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I able to see the front end. Now I have started the `server.js` from the folder location `src/` but still I can see it is calling `localhost:8000/service/listofblogs:` 
How do i fix the issue, could someone please advise ?

This is my package.json settings

```
{
  "name": "myblogs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    .....
     
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
    ....
  }
}
```

.env file

```
DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true
REACT_APP_URL=http://somedomain-test.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read the docs correctly, you have it backwards. See [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

> To tell the development server to proxy any unknown requests **to your API server** in development, add a proxy field to your package.json, for example:
>
> ```js
> "proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
> ```

But you say "rather than localhost:8000", but that is the url your proxy is giving the app.

Change it to the url you want to hit.